# Is word a keyword in node js?

Tags: node.js

I run this program

```
function execute(someFunction, value) {
someFunction(value);
}
execute(function(word){ console.log(word) }, "Hello");
```

The output is `Hello`

I didn't find any reference to word in node.js official docs.Is it possible that it is keyword in node.js.

Comment: `word` is simply the parameter name chosen by the author for the anonymous function./

Comment: @tymeJV so where the author is passing this parameter because if i remove word i don't get the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute` takes a callback and another parameter. What you see is the second parameter being passed into the anonymous function. "Hello" is being passed as `value`, that `value` is then passed into the callback, which has defined `word` as the parameter.

```
execute(function(word) { //<--the function is the "someFunction" parameter
    console.log(word) 
}, "Hello"); //<-- there is the "value" parameter
```

Comment: I know that callback and `Hello` is passed as a parameter to execute function but how the value is passed to callback that is what I am asking?

Comment: @TruePS -- `someFunction(value)` is where it gets passed.

Comment: Just one last question when `someFunction(value)` passes hello to somefunction parameter then output is obtained from somefunction parameter.Is this right or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, these are the JS reserved words.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

But it looks like you are a little confused as to where the `word` variable comes from.

Comment: Actually I am newbie in node.js and I started it today so what I am asking is what is the use of `word` here because if I don't write it i don't get the output.